# I tried to change the link of the page changing it's window.location, but it just doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, window.location

I have a function with the following code:

```js
window.location = window.location.origin;
```

and I've tried a lot of different ways of doing this, but they all just reload the page with the same link. The odd thing to me is that if I call this function from the console it all works out as it should, so I have no clue to where is the problem.

Comment: _"but they all have the same result"_ - which is ...?

Comment: And what are you _trying_ to do with this? If you just want to redirect to the root of your page, then why don't you simply do `window.location = "/";`?

Comment: oh I just realized that I forgot that part, I'm sorry. It just like, reloads the same page, but it doesn't change the link @CBroe

Comment: I tryed that and got the same thing @CBroe

Comment: Then show a proper [mre] of your issue, please, and not just a single line of code without any context.

Comment: that's just it... The function have only one line of code, and I'm shure I'm calling it correctelly in the html because I've tested it. I have no ideia where is the problem, cause it really should be working as far as I know. @CBroe

Comment: Are you trying to change the URL on the address bar without loading the page?